# jqueryのautocompleteがios/safariで2回タップしないと選択できない

Tags: jquery

jqueryのautocompleteを実装したのですが、ios/safariで２回タップしないと選択できない挙動をしております。

ほぼ同じ内容の質問が英語版のstackoverflowにあり試してみました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286685/autocomplete-requires-you-to-click-twice-in-ios-after-update-to-1-11-0

以下の対処法だと、挙動自体は想定したものになるのですが、少し強引な気がしています。

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover mouseenter');
    }
});
```

もう一つの方法は実装してみたのですが、うまく想定した通りの挙動をしませんでした。

```
$('.autocompleteContainer').on('touchstart', 'li.ui-menu-item', function(){

    var $container = $(this).closest('.autocompleteContainer'),
        $item = $(this);

    //if we haven't closed the result box like we should have, simulate a click on the element they tapped on.
    function fixitifitneedsit() {
        if ($container.is(':visible') && $item.hasClass('ui-state-focus')) {

            $item.trigger('click');
            return true; // it needed it
        }
        return false; // it didn't
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!fixitifitneedsit()) {
            setTimeout(fixitifitneedsit, 600);
        }
    }, 600);
});
```

もしうまく１回でタップし選択できるうまいやり方をご存知の方がいれば、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: リンクされていた質問で挙げられているサンプル(http://jsfiddle.net/35rmk2p6/4/show/)を試しても手元のiPad(iOS8.4)では再現しなかったのですが、このサンプルでも再現しますか？また、iOSのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: iOS8.4.1で`:hvoer`の仕様変更（バグ？）がまた出たようなので、それ関連じゃないでしょうか。（see [iOSでリンクを2回タップしないと画面遷移しない問題](http://keikenchi.com/ios-link-two-tap)）

Comment: @unarist バージョンは8.4.1です。

Comment: @quesera2 そうなんですね！情報ありがとうございます！検証してみます！